# arrows on whiskers of box plots

Tags: boxplot

I plotted box plots for a dataset of >20 million rows. The whiskers came out with little arrows pointing towards the boxes:
[image]

What do they mean?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could mention the specific software this came from. Best to also add the relevant tag.

Comment: The major messages here to me are that you may be better off on a transformed scale and that you have enough data points to look more closely at the distribution using e.g. a kernel density estimate.

Comment: Those aren't arrows.  They are horizontal lines (showing the fences) superimposed on individual point symbols (diamonds).

Answer (score 3):

It means nothing. It is a visual artefact of many black wheels overlayed on top black lines.

[image]

Comment: I am also thinking of a visual artifact where whiskers combine with points. But why would the points be more like diamond shape than round shape?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus because of low resolution.

Comment: I see now, the whiskers are not only a horizontal a stripe but also a vertical stripe. So the vertical stripe makes the circle a pointy shape.